# Oracle shift database on server side

Tags: oracle, connection

Are there a way to have oracle client connect to an other db/service on the serverside not changing tnsnames files on client's?

Comment: having two databases on same server , just want to test (all) clients against the new database.

Comment: Can you perhaps shut prod server down and run a virtual machine with new DB on same address?

Comment: Just change the connection details in the client application to point at the 2nd database. If you are asking if you can simultaneously run two databases on the same connection the that would be impossible.

Comment: are we talking about the same database in two different hosts ?  for example when Oracle is running on Data Guard with a primary side and a number of standby sites. ? If so, yes there is a way to configure tnsnames.ora to use TAF ( Transparent Application Failover ) with different sites and whether the database is move from A to B, you don't have to change the tnsnames,ora or anything in the client, when properly configured

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running the server on a VM and you swap out one VM for another at the same network address there is no way to handle what you are describing on the server side. DB connect strings on the client must be unique, and database-specific.

Comment: Thanks . That was what I was affraid off. Have then to either make a new vm or to change the clients tnsnames.

Comment: If you are running Oracle Restart, you can utilize "srvctl add|modify|start|stop service". Your client will connect to a designated SERVICE_NAME. By manipulating the service object, you can point the service to databaseA or databaseB - or  PDBa or PDBb.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt True. That generally requires use of RAC and/or ASM for storage and network management. It would still not be terribly dynamic, requiring (from experience) the deletion and recreation of the service object to point it to a new database.